# Trying to fetch a string from another form but i get string value null

Tags: c#

I have comboBox1, comboBox2 and a textBox on my first form. And when i click a button on this form i'm trying to send a text value from this items to the second form, and use this value in my connection string. I save textbox and combobox values in string on form 2.
So far i have done this, but it seems that the values in second form come null:

```
 //first form
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Form1 f2 = new Form1();
    f2.Text = comboBox2.Text;

    Form1 f3 = new Form1();
    f3.Text = comboBox1.Text;

    Form1 f4 = new Form1();
    f4.Text = textBox1.Text;

string selectedUser = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);

         if ((selectedUser == "admin") && (textBox1.Text == "password"))
        {
            Form1 form3 = new Form1();
            form3.Show();
            form3.Activate();
            this.Hide();
        }

}
//second form
public partial class Form1 : Form                  
{
    private string text1;
    public string Text1
    {
        get { return text1; }
        set { Text1 = value; }
    }

    private string text2;
    public string Text2
    {
        get { return text2; }
        set { text2 = value; }
    }

    private string text3;
    public string Text3
    {
        get { return text3; }
        set { text3 = value; }
    }

    public Form1(Form1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string db = Text1;
        string user = Text2;
        string pass = Text3;

        String strConnection = @"Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog ="+db+"; User ID ="+user+"; Password ="+pass+";";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = con;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select table_name  from information_schema.tables";
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
            dtRecord.DefaultView.Sort = "table_name ASC";
            ComboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You create three _different_ instances of Form1 and we cannot see how do you display the form1 instance that should receive the values. You need only one instance, set its properties and then display (Show/ShowDialog) that instance

Comment: @Steve I have added code to my post for displaying form1 isntance.

Comment: As explained do not create 4 instances of Form1. You need just one instance, the one that you want to display. Capture the values in some temporary variables and set all the properties on the last instance created

Comment: @Steve Ohh i see. I was suspicious that it was something wrong with all this instances. Now i see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're creating three instances of `Form1`, I don't think that's intentional.
2. You're setting the `Text` property of the new instances, not your custom properties.

Solution: Replace the body of `button1_Click` with the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nextForm = new Form1();
    nextForm.Text1 = comboBox2.Text;
    nextForm.Text2 = comboBox1.Text;
    nextForm.Text3 = textBox1.Text;

    string selectedUser = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);

    if ((selectedUser == "admin") && (textBox1.Text == "password"))
    {
        nextForm.Show();
        nextForm.Activate();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i had my instances all messed up. Thank this works.